# How to run a class from another class

Tags: java, sql, class, arraylist, erd

I have a class `erdbuilder` and another class `SQL`. My `erdbuilder` class allows me to draw shapes and to stores them in an arraylist `Connection`. Then I access the arraylist `Connection` from the `SQL` class where I will retrieve the data from the arraylist. I have a main class in `erdbuilder` class

I would like to run the `SQL` class from the `erdbuilder` class

I have this to access my `SQL` class but am not sure if it's the right way to do it.

**Here is part of my code to call the `SQL` class from the `erdbuilder` class**

```
if ((rect != null) && (ell != null)) {
con.add(new Connection(rect,ell));
System.out.println("Size of ArrayList <Connection> is:" + con.size());                                   
                                SQL sql = new SQL();
                                sql.display();                                                                      
                            }
```

**and here is my `SQL` class.**

```
package project;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import project.ERDBUILDER.DrawingBoard.Attribute;
import project.ERDBUILDER.DrawingBoard.Connection;
import project.ERDBUILDER.DrawingBoard.NamedShape;


public class SQL {    

    public void display() {
        ArrayList<Connection> con = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int a = 0; a < con.size(); a++) {
                                    NamedShape f = con.get(a).getNamedShape1();
                                    Attribute g = con.get(a).getNamedShape2();
                                    String i = f.getName();
                                    String j = g.getName();

                                    Shape y = f.getShape();
                                    Shape y1 = g.getShape();
                                    System.out.println(i + " AND " + j + " are linked");

    }



}
}
```

Actually when i run the `erdbuilder` class, it's not calling the `sql` class. What is wrong? Anyone can help me solve this?

Comment: Are you supposed to be (re)declaring your array list within SQL.display() via ArrayList<Connection> con = new ArrayList<>();? Seems like con is an existing array list created outside the scope of the SQL class, meaning it should be an argument to display and not newly declared as a local variable.

Comment: It is running. But when you run it, `con` is a newly-created array list, so it is empty, so the loop doesn't even start.

Comment: it's either (rect == ell == null), or con.size()==0; (there is no such thing as 
"not calling" in java. it's compiles right?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `display()`, you're iterating over an empty List.  Change the method to accept an argument of type List, and then when you call it, pass `con` (your ArrayList).

Here are your snippets edited as described:

```
if ((rect != null) && (ell != null)) {
con.add(new Connection(rect,ell));
System.out.println("Size of ArrayList <Connection> is:" + con.size());                                   
                            SQL sql = new SQL();
                            sql.display(con);                                                                      
                        }
```

...

```
package project;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.util.List;
import project.ERDBUILDER.DrawingBoard.Attribute;
import project.ERDBUILDER.DrawingBoard.Connection;
import project.ERDBUILDER.DrawingBoard.NamedShape;


public class SQL {    

public void display(List<Connection> con) {

    for (int a = 0; a < con.size(); a++) {
                                NamedShape f = con.get(a).getNamedShape1();
                                Attribute g = con.get(a).getNamedShape2();
                                String i = f.getName();
                                String j = g.getName();

                                Shape y = f.getShape();
                                Shape y1 = g.getShape();
                                System.out.println(i + " AND " + j + " are linked");

}



}
}
```

Comment: SUCCESS!! Thank you so much !! Superbe!

Answer (score 1):

The question is pretty vague, as there is no concept of "running" a class. I am not sure what you mean "when I run the erdbuilder class, it's not calling the sql class". What exactly are you running?

From the snippet of erdbuilder, you are indeed creating an instance of `SQL` and calling its `display` method. However, one thing that looks very strange is that inside `display` you are creating a new empty list of connections, and then iterating through it, expecting to find some elements. This list is newly created and will always be empty, so the code will never actually do anything. It seems you intended to pass the list you created in erdbuilder into the `display` method as a parameter...?

Answer (score 1):

You must pass the List into SQL:

```
public class SQL {    
    private List<Connection> con;
    public SQL( List<Connection> con ){
        this.con = con;
    }
    public void display() {
        // ArrayList<Connection> con = new ArrayList<>();
```

And create an SQL object and pass the list from erdbuilder.

```
SQL sql = new SQL( con );
sql.display();
```

It depends on other methods of SQL als requiring access to this List. Otherwise passing it as a parameter just to display may be preferable.

Comment: i made a mistake, infact am not creating another arraylist but using the arraylist from my class ERDBUILDER, "ERDBUILDER.DrawingBoard.Connection"

Comment: That's what I was trying to convey, like others.

Comment: Thank you so much, always ready to help :) I did find the solution. I was struggling with this.